# bug: spring security doesn't disting between roles

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, user-roles, spring-security-rest

i have this spring security config, the idea is secure the endpoint for the only the user with the role "CARD-OWNER" have access to the data

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/cashcards/**")
                                .hasRole("CARD-OWNER")
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService testOnlyUsers(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.builder();
        UserDetails sarah = users
                .username("sarah1")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("abc123"))
                .roles("CARD-OWNER") // new role
                .build();

        UserDetails hankOwnsNoCards = users
                .username("hank-owns-no-cards")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("qrs456"))
                .roles("NO-OWNER") // new role
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(sarah, hankOwnsNoCards);

    }
}
```

and this test class

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class CashCardApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void shouldRejectUsersWhoAreNotCardOwners() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                .withBasicAuth("hank-owns-no-cards", "qrs456")
                .getForEntity("/cashcards/99", String.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

when i run the test using the user with the wrong role i receive a 200 ok status code.

```
Request received for GET '/cashcards/99':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@40169f6d

servletPath:/cashcards/99
pathInfo:null
headers: 
authorization: Basic aGFuay1vd25zLW5vLWNhcmRzOnFyczQ1Ng==
accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
user-agent: Java/17.0.7
host: localhost:54415
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************




expected: 403 FORBIDDEN
 but was: 200 OK
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
expected: 403 FORBIDDEN
 but was: 200 OK
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at app//com.example.cashcard.CashCardApplicationTests.shouldRejectUsersWhoAreNotCardOwners(CashcardApplicationTests.java:28)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

CashCardApplicationTests > shouldRejectUsersWhoAreNotCardOwners() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at CashcardApplicationTests.java:28
2023-06-27T09:54:04.379-03:00  INFO 7544 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:2c11477f-771a-4e96-bfa7-eaf7b666dc21;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
1 test completed, 1 failed
```

but when i change the users details for both user have the wrong role the test pass

```
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService testOnlyUsers(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        User.UserBuilder users = User.builder();
        UserDetails sarah = users
                .username("sarah1")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("abc123"))
                .roles("NO-OWNER") // new role
                .build();

        UserDetails hankOwnsNoCards = users
                .username("hank-owns-no-cards")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("qrs456"))
                .roles("NO-OWNER") // new role
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(sarah, hankOwnsNoCards);

    }
```

i maked distinct proobs, but always that 1 user have the correct role, all the other pass the filter.

---

i find the bug, i don't know why but i when use this userDetails declaration:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService testOnlyUsers(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    User.UserBuilder users = User.builder();
    UserDetails sarah = users
            .username("sarah1")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("abc123"))
            .roles("CARD-OWNER") // new role
            .build();

    UserDetails hankOwnsNoCards = users
            .username("hank-owns-no-cards")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("qrs456"))
            .roles("NO-OWNER") // new role
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(sarah, hankOwnsNoCards);

}
```

spring add the fist user roles a the others

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=sarah1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_CARD-OWNER]]
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=hank-owns-no-cards, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_CARD-OWNER, ROLE_NO-OWNER]]
```

but with this User Details declaration the test pass and this role concatenation don't happen

```
 @Bean
public UserDetailsService testOnlyUsers(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    UserDetails sarah = User.builder()
            .username("sarah1")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("abc123"))
            .roles("CARD-OWNER") // new role
            .build();
    UserDetails hankOwnsNoCards = User.builder()
            .username("hank-owns-no-cards")
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode("qrs456"))
            .roles("NO-OWNER") // new role
            .build();
    
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(sarah, hankOwnsNoCards);

}
```

Comment: enable spring security TRACE logs and edit your question to include the FULL logs, not parts of the logs, the FULL logs during the test so we can see what is actually happening.

Comment: Please add your full test class.

Comment: sure, i add both, the full test class and the full logs